Ubuntu studio 24.04 with pipewire (and no studio controls anymore): How do I bridge between pulseaudio and jackd?
Ubuntu studio 24.04 is now using pipewire as it's default sound system. As a consequence the good old "Studio Controls" have been pulled without a working replacement.
With that the ability to fairly easily create pulseaudio - jack bridges through the studio controls has been removed as well.
So what is the new way to bridge between Pulseaudio and Jack? I do need multiple bridges with different names (was easy with Studio Controls), and not just a single "dummy device".

Per the release notes and release announcement, that setup (jackd + pulseaudio) is no longer officially supported and Studio Controls, in its form, has ceased development for more than a year (it is not an Ubuntu Studio project) and does not work with Pipewire at all. Pipewire has been in production on Ubuntu Studio for more than a year now.
I'm pretty sure we have discussed this at length via Matrix chat in that each application is given a spot on the grid, regardless of jack or pulseaudio or native Pipewire support. As such, we came to a discussion that Pulseaudio no longer needs to be "bridged" per se.
Per our discussions, your needs had to do with automatic connections, which can be facilitated by session managers such as RaySession, which is included by default in Ubuntu Studio. I have used it at length and it works.
